# Undefined errors generated by rxjs switchmap used with filter (Angular 2 + ngrx/store + redux)

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I'm working in an Angular 2.3 app using ngrx/store + the redux pattern.

In pulling a list of objects from my store (i.e. big image at the top of pages), I'm getting an undefined error that I'm trying to troubleshoot. It looks like it might be a race condition where the function is resolving prior to the observable. In any case, I'm still getting the result but trying to understand the error:

```
error_handler.js:50 EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
```

I have in the constructor (which has `private _store: Store`)

```
objects$: Observable<Object[]> = _store.select(s => s.objects)
```

and my function is:

```
selectObject(id: number): Observable<Object> {
    return this.objects$
      .switchMap( objects => objects.filter( object => object.id === id));
}
```

Comment: It might be a TypeScript error. If `objects` is an array, try `objects$: Observable<Array> = _store.select(s => s.objects)`

Comment: I've added an answer regarding the error mentioned in your question, but why are you using the `switchMap` operator? `switchMap` merges an observable, but you appear to be returning an array.

Comment: @cartant using switchMap because I'm returning an observable (containing an array) from the store. All new data goes into the store via a reducer sending in a payload (in this case the array of objects generates the new state) and from the store I get an observable of the latest state.

Comment: According to the declaration - `objects$: Observable<Object[]>` - it emits an array of objects and not an observable. Anyway, I've voted to close this as you've posted an answer stating the the problem was upstream, so I think this is a problem-is-not-reproducible-anymore situation.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that the state does not contain an `objects` property (or the property is `undefined` in the initial state) and that your `select` operator is then emitting `undefined` :

```
_store.select(s => s.objects)
```

There is no mention in your question of the structure of the state, so there is not much more to say.

To confirm that this is the problem, you could add some logging to the selector:

```
_store.select(s => { console.log(`objects = ${s.objects}`); return s.objects; })
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. Issue not surprisingly ended up coming from how I was calling the function upstream, where I had a condition that called it before it was populated, but then called it again after it was populated, hence it worked but threw an error.